# Button not showing when using JS to dynamically add to page

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

```js
function addElements(mailbox) {
  if (mailbox != 'sent') {
    let actionDivArchiveBtn = document.querySelector('#actions')
    let archiveButton = document.createElement("button");
    archiveButton.classList.add('archive');
    archiveButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
    actionDivArchiveBtn.appendChild(archiveButton);

    archiveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (email.archived === false) {
        actionDivArchiveBtn.style.color = "blue";
        fetch(`/emails/archive/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: true
          })
        })
      } else {
        actionDivArchiveBtn.style.color = "black";
        fetch(`/emails/archive/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: false
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
  load_mailbox('inbox');
}
```

```html
<div class="actions">
  <span class="action"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <span class="from">${email.sender}</span>
  <span class="date">
                            <span class="float-right"></span>${email.timestamp}</span>
</div>
<div class="title">${email.subject}</div>
<div class="description">${email.body}</div>
```

I am creating a gmail like single page application, I want to create an archive button dynamically using vanilla javascript (the button is not showing on my screen) and I want to listen to when the user clicks on the archive button using event listeners then check if archive is true using  PUT and change to false and vice versa.

The problem I am having is that my button is not showing.

I don't know why because I've checked similar examples of how to to create and append buttons and similar process was taken. Please help with a code review.

```
                        <div class="actions">
                            <span class="action"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="header">
                            <span class="from">${email.sender}</span>
                            <span class="date">
                            <span class="float-right"></span>${email.timestamp}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="title">${email.subject}</div>
                        <div class="description">${email.body}</div>
```

```
function addElements(mailbox) {
      if (mailbox != 'sent'){
        let actionDivArchiveBtn = document.querySelector('#actions')
        let archiveButton = document.createElement("button");
        archiveButton.classList.add('archive');
        archiveButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
        actionDivArchiveBtn.appendChild(archiveButton);

        archiveButton.addEventListener('click',() => {
          if (email.archived === false) {



function addElements(mailbox) {
  if (mailbox != 'sent') {
    let actionDivArchiveBtn = document.querySelector('#actions')
    let archiveButton = document.createElement("button");
    archiveButton.classList.add('archive');
    archiveButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
    actionDivArchiveBtn.appendChild(archiveButton);

    archiveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (email.archived === false) {
        actionDivArchiveBtn.style.color = "blue";
        fetch(`/emails/archive/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: true
          })
        })
      } else {
        actionDivArchiveBtn.style.color = "black";
        fetch(`/emails/archive/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: false
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
  load_mailbox('inbox');
}
<div class="actions">
  <span class="action"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <span class="from">${email.sender}</span>
  <span class="date">
                            <span class="float-right"></span>${email.timestamp}</span>
</div>
<div class="title">${email.subject}</div>
<div class="description">${email.body}</div>






function addElements(mailbox) {
  if (mailbox != 'sent') {
    let actionDivArchiveBtn = document.querySelector('#actions')
    let archiveButton = document.createElement("button");
    archiveButton.classList.add('archive');
    archiveButton.innerHTML = `<i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
    actionDivArchiveBtn.appendChild(archiveButton);

    archiveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (email.archived === false) {
        actionDivArchiveBtn.style.color = "blue";
        fetch(`/emails/archive/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: true
          })
        })
      } else {
        actionDivArchiveBtn.style.color = "black";
        fetch(`/emails/archive/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: false
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
  load_mailbox('inbox');
}
<div class="actions">
  <span class="action"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>
<div class="header">
  <span class="from">${email.sender}</span>
  <span class="date">
                            <span class="float-right"></span>${email.timestamp}</span>
</div>
<div class="title">${email.subject}</div>
<div class="description">${email.body}</div>
```

Comment: Please move your code into Code Snippet (press Ctrl+M in editor) and show HTML layout!

Comment: instead of pasting the whole code bound to your context ... why don't you simplify the problem trying to better understand what you are doing wrong? for example `document.querySelector('actions')` I doubt it will ever return any result since do you have html element type actions??

Comment: `// select the div housing the archive and reply button` - you are not selecting any div, `document.querySelector('actions')` would try to find an element with the _tag name_ `actions`.

Comment: @EzioMercer, I think I've done that, pressed Ctrl + M and Save & insert into post.

Comment: @Chuks Your code is not runnable so no, you didn't done that. There must be a "Run code snippet` button

Comment: @CBroe, shoot, I've edited that to let actionDivArchiveBtn = document.querySelector('#actions'). Thanks for the observation. My button is not showing still

Comment: Then your code to add the button in itself should work fine, https://jsfiddle.net/a6fq2e84/ You'll need to do a bit more debugging yourself then, we can't do that for you based on the mere snippet you have shown.

Comment: @EzioMercer, I have now, haven't used it before so I thought I had added it. Thanks

Comment: @Chuks Thank you! Now remove your code under Code Snippet and add your HTML layout into HTML block of Code Snippet

Comment: I've added my HTML and removed the other code that wasn't in the Code Snippet

Comment: @Chuks You can (should) add your HTML layout and JS code into one Code Snippet. Code Snippet has 4 sections, where 3 of them for editing (HTML block at the top left, CSS block at the top right and JS block at the bottom left) and 1 for see output. And don't forget to press "Tidy" button in Code Snippet before pressing "Save & insert into post"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `querySelector` for `actionDivArchiveBtn` is incorrect. Because you search by `id` but in layout it is `class` so I changed in layout `class` to `id` and now it works. But may be you need `class` in layout then change `#` to `.` in `querySelector`:

```js
function load_mailbox(string) {
  console.log(string);
}

function addElements(mailbox) {
  if (mailbox != 'sent') {
    let actionDivArchiveBtn = document.querySelector('#actions')
    let archiveButton = document.createElement("button");
    archiveButton.classList.add('archive');
    archiveButton.innerHTML = `SOME TEXT<i class="fa fa-archive" aria-hidden="true"></i>`
    actionDivArchiveBtn.appendChild(archiveButton);

    archiveButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      if (email.archived === false) {
        actionDivArchiveBtn.style.color = "blue";
        fetch(`/emails/archive/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: true
          })
        })
      } else {
        actionDivArchiveBtn.style.color = "black";
        fetch(`/emails/archive/${id}`, {
          method: 'PUT',
          body: JSON.stringify({
            archived: false
          })
        })
      }
    })
  }
  load_mailbox('inbox');
}

addElements('receive');
```

```html
<div id="actions">
  <span class="action"><i class="fa fa-reply" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="header">
  <span class="from">${email.sender}</span>
  
  <span class="date">
    <span class="float-right"></span>${email.timestamp}
  </span>
</div>

<div class="title">${email.subject}</div>

<div class="description">${email.body}</div>
```